# TypeError when using React: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Sometimes, when using React libraries, such as [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
>   /~/react-router/~/react/lib/ReactMount.js?:606

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This error is commonly caused by [two versions of React loaded alongside](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2402).

For example, if you `npm install` a package that requires a different React version and puts it into `dependencies` instead of `peerDependencies`, it might install a separate React into `node_modules/<some library using React>/node_modules/react`.

Two different Reacts won't play nicely together (at least yet).

To fix it, just delete `node_modules/<some library using React>/node_modules/react`.
If you see a library putting React in `dependencies` instead of `peerDependencies`, file an issue.

Comment: It might also happens when using `require('react')` & `require('react/addons')` in separate files.

Comment: I found it also happens to me when testing with Jest. If I require react globally, depends on the test it throws that error. The workaround I found is to require react every time inside beforeEach.

Comment: @FerranNegre Are you sure you don't have duplicate React in some `node_modules` subfolder?

Comment: Similar to what @Cethy is saying, using `require('react')` and `require('React')` will also throw this error.

Comment: react-select does this  https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/package.json#L15

Comment: @Marwan File an issue with them!

Comment: This is misinformation. Right cause (duplicate Reacts) wrong solution (peerDependencies). Some libraries, react-select included, require react and cannot function without it as a dependency. The solution is for libraries to be as forgiving as possible with their dependencies, and to always ensure you're including a version of React that satisfies the requirements of packages you're using.

Comment: @JedWatson How do you propose to deal with stuff breaking when new version of React comes out? At least peer deps tell whether authors think the library is ready. What's the right way to solve this without peer deps?

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I ran into this issue because I was inadvertently attempting to unmount a component before a click event had finished bubbling. I fixed it by simply adding `event.stopPropagation()` in my click handler.

Comment: @AlienBishop Your solution worked for me but I'm not sure why. Could you add it as an answer with a little more explanation? I promise to upvote. :)

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone has this issue having `npm link`ed two modules depending on react, I found a solution...

Let's say you have Parent depending on React, and Child depending on react. When you do:

`cd ../child
npm link
cd ../parent
npm link child`

This causes this problem, because parent and child will each load their own instance of React.

The way to fix this is as follows:

`cd parent
cd node_modules/react
npm link
cd ../../../child
npm link react`

This ensures your parent project supplies the react dependency, even when linked, which is how npm would resolve the dependency when you are unlinked.

Answer (score 4):

Using `require('react')` and `require('React')` inconsistently causes this problem as well, even if you only have one version of React.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify didn't have this problem. Once I stopped using gulp-browserify and switched to watchify+browserify, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined` started happening.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me peerDependencies is not getting traction. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5080#issuecomment-40545599

I am maintaining [react-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) (and other react modules), and what I've done until now is to specify the React dependency using the caret, for example ^0.12.0.

Also, when doing a build will all concatenated files, for use outside of the npm ecosystem, I use webpack with
`externals: { 'react': 'React'}`
which will look for the global var `React`.

Comment: It's a mistake in the same way democracy is “the worst form of government except for all others” IMO. When 0.13 comes out, your plugin will install just fine although it may be incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I was using a `<Link>` from react-router inside a `<NavItem>` from react-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this crash while server side rendering and none of these answers are the problem, here's the likely culprit:

Doing something async (setTimeout, AJAX, etc.) in componentWillMount. Since componentWillMount is called on the server, this setTimeout/request will still fire. If you setState inside this callback then it'll cause the error above.