# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined in React, React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My code was fine until I tried demoing a ReactBootstrap Modal. When I initialized the `show` prop passed to my Modal component from my top-level component to true (`this.state.showResult` in `QuizApp`), I keep getting
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined`
When `showResult` is initialized to false, it works fine.

#### The error occurs whenever `show` prop of Modal is set to true.

Eventually I'll have event handlers that set `showResult` to true, but for now I just wanted to see what the Modal would look like, thus initializing `showResult: true`.

The only relevant information I could find was that this error is caused by multiple versions of React on the same page, but I don't think that applies here. I'm creating a really simple app, doing all my transpiling/building in the browser itself, no pre-building with `node`
[TypeError when using React: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153166/typeerror-when-using-react-cannot-read-property-firstchild-of-undefined)

What makes the situation even more confusing is that `show` is a newly added prop that shows up in the code examples on ReactBootstrap docs but I couldn't find anything written about it in the docs.
[How to open/close react-bootstrap modal programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471368/how-to-open-close-react-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

#### class QuizApp

```
class QuizApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { quiz: {questions: []}, showResult: true };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var quizRef = new Firebase('https://firequiz.firebaseio.com/quizzes/' + this.props.i);
    quizRef.on('value', snapshot => this.setState({
      quiz: snapshot.val()
    }));
  }
  render() {
    let closeResult = e => this.setState({ showResult: false });
    return (
      <div>
        {quizHeader}
        <QuestionList data={this.state.quiz.questions}/>
        <Result show={this.state.showResult} onHide={closeResult} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### class Result

```
class Result extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal {...this.props} bsSize='medium' aria-labelledby='contained-modal-title-md'>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id='contained-modal-title-md'>Your score</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          hello
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/prashcr/pen/NqVbzE

Comment: Just replace <Modal> With <Modal.Dialog>     http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbwMEy

Comment: WTF?! Thank you so much. Where did you find this? Also, how do I get the backdrop to turn dark like in the demo?

Comment: I referred the docs here http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals.  For modal with a background you should use this http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live

Comment: The modal with background example is exactly what I used...it also uses Modal instead of Modal.Dialog. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Modal.Dialog is a static component, it appears regardless of its show prop. Can't make it appear/disappear on event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed a conflict with two different `react` versions. The `react-bootstrap` build I was using was bundled with `react 0.14`, while the `react` I was using was `0.13.3`

Using [v0.24.5](https://rawgit.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap-bower/v0.24.5/react-bootstrap.min.js) build of `react-bootstrap` instead, fixed the issue.

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1179